# Regex - Select value of query string value and stop at first ampersand

Tags: regex, tomcat, web

I am trying to use regex to match a query string pattern and am having some issues.  The URL is "http:www.domain.com/dir/page.aspx".  This page can have a variety of query string vaiables and values attached in a non-specific order.  What i want to do is get the value of one of these variables and use it.  Thus, for all of these examples:

```
http:\\www.domain.com/dir/page.aspx?city=name
http:\\www.domain.com/dir/page.aspx?area=codes&city=name
http:\\www.domain.com/dir/page.aspx?area=codes&city=name&state=ofmind
http:\\www.domain.com/dir/page.aspx?city=name&state=ofmind
http:\\www.domain.com/dir/page.aspx?area=codes&state=ofmind&city=name
http:\\www.domain.com/dir/page.aspx?area=codes&city=name&state=ofmind&dat=dis&foo=bar
```

I want to extract the value "name" from the city variable and use it.  What I've come up thus far is:

```
/dir\/page.aspx\?(.*&)?city=(.*)(?=&.*)/
```

and using $2 for that value.

This works ok for some cases but doesnt seem to catch them all.  I believe my issue is here:

```
city=(.*)
```

and that I need to stop capturing at the first appearance of an ampersand, but my random copy and paste efforts have not been successful.  Can anyone explain how I would catch any and all characters until a particular one appears?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Note, the difference between this and the duplicate is that here you're not using `.location` - so swap that out when you use that code.

Comment: Quit edit here.  I'm working primarily in javascript but I mislabeld this question.  I'm actually looking to do this within a Tomcat redirect rule

Comment: are you trying to do the matching in javascript regex?

Comment: I'm testing my patterns using javascript but this will be deployed as a redirect rule on Tomcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be on capture `$2`

```
/dir\/page.aspx\?(.*&)?city=([^&]*)/
```

This will be on capture `$1`

```
/dir\/page.aspx\?(?:.*&)?city=([^&]*)/
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully.  I ended up using the second example (the one returning $1) for simplicity.  Thanks!